# Python matplotlib.animation Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, matplotlib-animation

I use Windows 10 / 64 / Google chrome

I found a good set-up for animation over Jupyter with the call %matplotlib notebook as here :

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as st
%matplotlib notebook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
```

For exemple, this one is working pretty well :

```
n = 100
X = st.norm(0,1).rvs(200)
number_of_frames = np.size(X)

def update_hist(num, second_argument):
    plt.cla()
    plt.hist(X[:num], bins = 20)
    plt.title("{}".format(num))
    plt.legend()

fig = plt.figure()
hist = plt.hist(X)

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_hist, number_of_frames, fargs=(X, ), repeat = False )
plt.show()
```

But, weirdly the code below doesn't work while it's the same structure, it puzzles me :

```
X = np.linspace(-5,5, 150)
number_of_frames = np.size(X)
N_max = 100
N = np.arange(1,N_max+1)
h = 1/np.sqrt(N)

def update_plot(n, second_argument):
    #plt.cla()
    plt.plot(X, [f(x) for x in X], c = "y", label = "densité")
    plt.plot(X, [fen(sample_sort[:n],h[n],x) for x in X], label = "densité")
    plt.title("n = {}".format(n))

fig = plt.figure(6)
plot = plt.plot(X, [f(x) for x in X], c = "y", label = "densité")
    
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_plot, number_of_frames, fargs=(X, ), repeat = False )
plt.show()
```

Thanks for your help, best regards.

EDIT : You don't have the funciton fen(sample_sort[:n],h[n],x) it is a function from float to float taking a x in argument and returning a flot. The argument sample_sort[:n],h[n] it is just maths things I'm trying to understand some statistics anyway, you can remplace with line with what you want np.cos(N[:n]) for exemple.

EDIT : New code according to the suggestion :

```
N_max = 100
X = np.linspace(-5,5, N_max )
number_of_frames = np.size(X)
N = np.arange(1,N_max+1)
h = 1/np.sqrt(N)

def update_plot(n):
    #plt.cla()
    lines.set_data(X, np.array([fen(sample_sort[:n],h[n],x) for x in X]))
    ax.set_title("n = {}".format(n))
    return lines

fig = plt.figure()

ax = plt.axes(xlim=(-4, 4), ylim=(-0.01, 1))
ax.plot(X, np.array([f(x) for x in X]), 'y-', lw=2, label="d")
lines, = ax.plot([], [], 'b--', lw=3, label="f")

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_plot, number_of_frames, repeat = False )
plt.show()
```

EDIT 2:

I found a code over internet which does exactly what I would like

```
# Fermi-Dirac Distribution
def fermi(E: float, E_f: float, T: float) -> float:
    return 1/(np.exp((E - E_f)/(k_b * T)) + 1)

# Create figure and add axes
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 4))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

# Get colors from coolwarm colormap
colors = plt.get_cmap('coolwarm', 10)

# Temperature values
T = np.array([100*i for i in range(1,11)])

# Create variable reference to plot
f_d, = ax.plot([], [], linewidth=2.5)

# Add text annotation and create variable reference
temp = ax.text(1, 1, '', ha='right', va='top', fontsize=24)

# Set axes labels
ax.set_xlabel('Energy (eV)')
ax.set_ylabel('Fraction')

# Animation function
def animate(i):
    x = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
    y = fermi(x, 0.5, T[i])
    f_d.set_data(x, y)
    f_d.set_color(colors(i))
    temp.set_text(str(int(T[i])) + ' K')
    temp.set_color(colors(i))

# Create animation
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=range(len(T)), interval=500, repeat=False)

# Ensure the entire plot is visible
fig.tight_layout()

# show animation
plt.show()
```

Comment: There also is a function f() not defined, what sort of error does the code return?

Comment: Indeed ! You can choose f = np.cos. And there's no error but the thing is there's no animation, I only get the plot :  plot = plt.plot(X, [f(x) for x in X], c = "y", label = "densité")

Comment: `lines.set_data(X, np.array([fen(sample_sort[:n],h[n],x) for x in X]))`In the animation function, the length of X and Y need to be the same, so it should be `X[:n]`.

Answer (score 3):

What I want to draw is a curve at random because the actual state of the function is unknown. The basic structure looks like this, so please modify it based on this.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as st
# %matplotlib notebook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
# from IPython.display import HTML
# from matplotlib.animation import PillowWriter

X = np.linspace(-5,5, 100)
number_of_frames = np.size(X)
N_max = 100
N = np.arange(1,N_max+1)
h = 1/np.sqrt(N)

def update_plot(n):
    #plt.cla()
    lines.set_data(X[:n], h[:n])
    lines2.set_data(X[:n], h[:n]*-1)
    ax.set_title("n = {}".format(n))
    return lines, lines2

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(-5, 5), ylim=(-1, 1))
lines, = ax.plot([], [], 'y-', lw=2, label="densité")
lines2, = ax.plot([], [], 'b--', lw=3, label="densité2")

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_plot, frames=number_of_frames, repeat=False )
plt.show()
# ani.save('lines_ani2.gif', writer='pillow')

# plt.close()
# HTML(ani.to_html5_video())
```

[image]

Comment: Cheers, I fancy : ax.set_title("n = {}".format(n)) in your code because even if you return lines, lines2 your function still provide a legend. Your code works on my laptop.

Comment: But mine still doesn't work, I add it in the first post. It means I have a empty figure

Comment: X is set to 150, but x and y need to be the same, so I set mine to 100.

Comment: Also, you need to set the drawing range of the graph, so you need to modify it to the range of your function. `ax = plt.axes(xlim=(-5, 5), ylim=(-1, 1))`

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem as my f takes place as plt.axes(xlim=(-4,4), ylim=(0, 0.6))

Comment: I edited my post taking your suggestions into my code. It is unfortunaly still the same, there's one thing to notice our code are not exactly the same. I plot for each n two function f and f_n and then my animation shows how f_n evolves in time. I know it doesn't really matter for our bugs but it is still worth to notice.

Comment: I deleted : fargs=(X, ) and then the yellow plot came in ! I'm getting closer the need the blue plot now :D

Comment: About X, I've tried 
T = np.array([fen(sample_sort[:1],h[1],x) for x in X])
print(T.shape)
It is (100,)

Comment: This is the fundamental logic of animation, and the n of the animation function is the key. So, we draw the data obtained by sequentially counting up n. In the code you have added, n is not working.

Comment: Adding EDIT 2 in the first post

Comment: Let's first understand the difference between your code `lines.set_data(X, np.array([f(x) for x in X]))` and my code `lines.set_data(X[:n], h[:n])`.

Comment: My line doesn't involve n

Comment: So what do you animate?

Comment: Even if I delete the line it does still not work.

Comment: I animate the second line lines2, lines was just a background I deleted it to check if it works it doesn't

Comment: The animation function has only the target to update the data sequentially. If you want to display the data from the beginning, place it outside the animation function. Also, have you checked the data that will be created in your lines2? For example, is the output `print(np.array([fen(sample_sort[:n],h[n],x))` as intended? Also, is it possible to draw it as a normal graph?

Comment: np.array([fen(sample_sort[:n],h[n],x) for x in X]) is (100,) array

Comment: np.array([fen(sample_sort[:n],h[n],x) for x in X]) can be ploted indeed, it's a nice graph for n = 2 but I check for n until 10000 it's okay

Comment: That's a step in the right direction. What part of that graph do you want to animate?

Comment: I have made the changes you advice me, update doesn't work but I have a yellow graph

Comment: I would like to animate like this : Plot x, step 1 plot x/2, step 2 plot x/3 ... step n plot x/(n+1) you will see an animation for x/n converges to 0

Comment: If you want to animate a decreasing number, you can just do `n*-1`.

Comment: Yeah I should give up for now.

Comment: I can't ask an other question with my account :'(

Comment: I mean as a completely new question.

Comment: I've reached the maximum questions I can ask for a while.

Comment: Was there a limit to the number of questions here(SO)?

Comment: I have no answer sir